# App inventor offline

Tags: android, download

Android has a developing tool called appinventor, do you have to be online to use it or is there a download or offline option?

Comment: I believe this question is more appropriate for http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Sam: Development questions, including the usage of development tools to create apps, are [off-topic on Android SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @eldarerathis thank you, I found that out the hard way

Answer (score 1):

App Inventor was taken over by MIT its [new home is here](http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/) I am almost certain that at least it used to need internet connection because it is run in a browser. So unless you are on a local network with the server that hosts you'd need internet access.

I haven't played with it any time recently but I just peeked in on it and it certainly looks to be the same way (operates in browser, syncs everything to cloud).

Answer (score 0):

App Inventor 2 can be run locally on your machine. You have to fork and clone the Git repo.

[Instructions on setting up App Inventor 2 Locally](http://josmas.github.io/contributingToAppInventor2/#/)